# What are the prime and maximal ideals of the power set of $\Bbb N$, i.e. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We Know that the power set of $\Bbb N$ with respect to the symmetric difference  and intersection, i.e. $\left(\mathcal P(\Bbb N),\triangle, \cap \right)$ is a commutative ring with identity.

My question is:

> What are the prime and maximal ideals of this ring? Can they be characterised?

Comment: Hint: $\cap$ serves as multiplication. So for $I$ to be an ideal, you want that for all $p\in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and $r \in I$ the inclusion $p \cap r \in I$ to hold. Can you come up with an easy classifications of the ideals?

Comment: @flawr: I know that what an ideal $I$ will look like: from definition it follows that $\emptyset\in I$, if $A,B\in I$, then $A\cap B\in I$ and if $A\in I$, then $I$ contains all subsets of $A$. But I want to know the characterisation of prime and maximal ideals.

Comment: @flawr That does not quite that easily give a classification except for principal ideals, since the addition also has to be respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every prime ideal in this ring is maximal.  There is not any nice explicit description of all the maximal ideals.  The only ones that you can explicitly describe are the *principal* maximal ideals: for any $x\in\mathbb{N}$ determines a maximal ideal consisting of all $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\not\in A$ (this ideal is principal, generated by $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{x\}$).  There are many other maximal ideals that are not principal, but none of them can be proved to exist without the axiom of choice.  A maximal ideal is nonprincipal iff it contains all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Here is a characterization of the maximal ideals in terms of familiar algebra of sets.  A subset $I\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a maximal ideal iff it has the following three properties:

- If $A\in I$ and $B\subseteq I$, then $B\in I$.
- If $A,B\in I$, then $A\cup B\in I$.
- For any $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, exactly one of $A$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is an element of $I$.

(All of these statements apply equally well to the ring $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for any set $X$, except that if $X$ is finite, there are no nonprincipal maximal ideals.)

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is any set, its power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), with symmetric difference and intersection as operations. Quoting [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), every prime ideal $P$ in a Boolean ring $R$ is maximal: the quotient ring $R/P$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_2$, which shows the maximality of $P$. Since maximal ideals are always prime, prime ideals and maximal ideals coincide in Boolean rings.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: One way of looking at $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$ is to regard it as a set of tuples $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$, where $A\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ is represented by the tuple $(\cdots,x_i,\cdots)$ with $x_i=1$ if $i\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. This way, $\Delta$ translates into coordinatewise addition mod $2$ and $\cap$ translates into coordinatewise multiplication mod $2$. It's not difficult to see that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\cong\Bbb{F}_2^{\Bbb{N}}$, the countably infinite direct product of fields of order $2$. Now, for any ring $R$ and ideal $I$, $I$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow R/I$ is an integral domain and $I$ is maximal $\Leftrightarrow R/I$ is a field. Can you take it from here?

Comment: not familiar with the quotient of the infinite direct product of fields. Please elaborate.